# What is this yellow-petaled, dark-eyed flower with hairless stems?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

The flower has 14 yellow petals and a brown center:

[image: flowers]

I'm hoping someone can identify it. It was by a pond in southern Utah. I thought it was a Brown-eyed Susan, but the stems are not hairy.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [*Helianthus debilis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helianthus_debilis), but without sight of the leaves, overall growth habit, together with height, it's hard to ID correctly.

Comment: Definitely looks like a type of helianthus (sunflower) to me. I used to live in southern Idaho, and these were a common sight along roads and ditches.